# Error 500 after returning value from WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a WCF service with some methods. It uses ASP.NET State Service. Client calling web methods is written in C++ using gSOAP. Everything works like a charm when ASP.NET State Service is running. When I stop this service web methods are invoked correctly, value is returned but client retrieves Internal Server Error (500). Why is this hapenning? Why web methods are invoked correctly?

I need to resolve this, because after receiving error 500 client retries to send data to web service and after that I have multiple rows with the same data in DB.

Comment: Error 500 indicate a problem with the WCF service, from experience the best way to catch these errors are to implement logging on your service. Use a component such as Log4Net, then you can at least trace any error causing the 500 error.

Comment: Error is not caused by my code. I already have logging and my code works fine. Data is send to web method, added to db, and success is returned. 500 error code is returned somwhere else and I do not know where...

Comment: Use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) to trace your request and responses, you should be able to determine the exact source of the 500 error.

Comment: Your code does not return a SOAP message, it returns a CLR object. WCF will then transform this object into a SOAP message, at which time a 500 error can be thrown for a variety of reasons, all caused by either your code (which created the object to return) or your configuration (which determines how the object is put on the wire and how sessions are handled and so on). Search this site for "WCF server error 500" and you'll see **many** hints on how you can find the source of the error. The easiest to set up is [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx).